# perl mmap script gave error because of "Invalid argument"

Tags: perl

Try to use perl mmap, but the example from document page ([Perl mmap](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Sys-Mmap-0.17/Mmap.pm)) gave error:

```
$ perl mmap.pl tmp.bin
mmap: mmap call failed: errno: 22 errmsg: Invalid argument  at mmap.pl line 5.
```

The code for mmap.pl

```
use Sys::Mmap;

open FILEHANDLE, "+<", $ARGV[0] || die "Failed to open $ARGV[0] $!\n";

mmap($foo, 0, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, FILEHANDLE) or die "mmap: $!";
@tags = $foo =~ /<(.*?)>/g;
munmap($foo) or die "munmap: $!";

mmap($bar, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, FILEHANDLE);
substr($bar, 1024, 11) = "Hello world";
```

Wonder how to fix it.

Comment: You should look at your operating system documentation for the `mmap(2)` system call. Pay attention the reasons that it can fail and set errno to EINVAL. If you still need help, you should [edit] your question to tell us what OS you're running this on, and include the relevant section of your system's mmap documentation.

Comment: What is $foo? You should put `use strict; use warnings;` to catch syntax errors. It seems to me Invalid argument could refer to $foo being empty, and this being unexpected / not allowed for mmap.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` will also catch typos in the name of the constants. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

Answer (score 2):

Turned out the file `tmp.bin` I passed in as parameter has 0 bytes.

I passed a non-empty file as the parameter, it works fine.

Thanks @kenster for the hint to check status code.